# If $Y\subseteq X:=\prod_{i\in I}X_i$ then there exist $Y_i\subseteq X_i$ for each $i\in I$ such that $Y=\prod_{i\in I}Y_i$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

**Statement**

If $Y\subseteq X:=\prod_{i\in I}X_i$ then there exist $Y_i\subseteq X_i$ for each $i\in I$ such that $Y=\prod_{i\in I}Y_i$.

Defining $Y_i:=\pi_i[Y]$ for each $i\in I$ then clearly $Y\subseteq\pi^{-1}_i[Y_i]$ for each $i\in I$ and so $Y\subseteq\bigcap_{i\in I}\pi^{-1}_i[Y_i]$ but un fortunately I don't be able to prove the other inclusion. So could someone help me, please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is false. For example, take $I = \{i, j\}$, $X_i = \{0, 1\}$, $X_j = \{a, b\}$. Then $X = X_i \times X_j = \{(0, a), (0, b), (1, a), (1, b)\}$. If we take $Y = \{(0, a), (1, b)\}$ then $Y$ is not a cartesian product.

Comment: Okay, but if I add some hypotesis about $Y$ then the statement could be true?

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro I mean, of course you could add the hypothesis "$Y$ is a cartesian product", but that pretty much trivialises the statement. I cannot think of a reasonable non-trivial hypothesis.

Comment: Okay, thanks too much for your assistance!